# How to select an image from gallery in xamarin forms?

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gallery

I'm trying to pick an image from gallery and i've done everything that is in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/photo-picker) doc, but i'm getting an error with the "image" object in my .cs implementation.

My .cs code:

```
 public partial class MyProfilePage : ContentPage
{
  
    public MyProfilePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = new MyProfileViewModel();
    }

   
    async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //(sender as Button).IsEnabled = true;

        Stream stream = await DependencyService.Get<IPhotoPickerService>().GetImageStreamAsync();
        if (stream != null)
        {
            
            image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);
        }

        (sender as Button).IsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: first, what does "an error" mean?  Telling us what the **specific** error is and what line it occurs on would be really useful information.  2nd, try using the Media plugin for Xamarin Forms instead of this approach

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO!

> but i'm getting an error with the "image" object in my .cs implementation.

You can check the **Xaml** file that whether contain the `x:Name="image"`.

Such as follows:

```
<ContentPage Title="Photo Picker"
             Icon="monkeyicon.png">
    <StackLayout Margin="20,35,20,20" >
        <Label Text="Photo Picker"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
        <Button Text="Pick Photo"
                Clicked="OnPickPhotoButtonClicked" />
        <Image x:Name="image" />
    </StackLayout>        
</ContentPage>
```

If not works , you can refer to following steps:

- **First**, you need to share the detail error logs here, and explain this occurs in iOS or
  Android.
- **Second**, you also can refer to this official sample **[Xamarin.Forms - Dependency Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/dependencyservice/)** to check where problem is.